# Why is the whole Users folder shared when sharing a folder inside it?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing

I've just noticed the most peculiar thing: When I share a folder inside `C:\Users`, the whole of `C:\Users` is shared.

For example, when I share `C:\Users\Public`, there won't be a `Public` share on my computer, but a `Users` share, from which one can navigate to the `Public` folder. And to any other folder in `C:\Users`! I've tried with other folders in my user folder with the same result.

From a security or privacy perspective, I find this behaviour very questionable. Why is this so?

The above is true when sharing a folder inside `C:\Users` via “Properties -> Sharing -> Share.” However, when sharing via “Properties -> Sharing -> Advanced Sharing,” only the selected folder is shared.

Again, why? Is there any imaginable use case for this behaviour?

Comment: So for clarification, if there is USERS\Joe , USERS\Mary, and USERS\Fred  all with say Outlook PST / OST Email files , you are getting all these folders and files?  That would indeed be strange. Does not happen here.

Comment: Also, on my machines (checking after I posted) there is only one Folder called Public in all of USERS and it is (of course) public. There are not public folders in each individual user profile.

Comment: I just tested again, I don't see folders of other users. But: When I share my Downloads folder for example, a Users share is created, which contains `Default`, `Public` and `myUser`. In `myUser` I can not only access Downloads, but also Documents, Desktop, Music and everything.

Comment: I just had this happen to me as well on Windows 10. Incredibly odd.

Comment: I just had this exact same creepy behavior happen with a brand new Windows 11 machine.  I shared 'Public' and then realized it had shared 'Users' instead!  So I "Stopped Sharing" Users, then tried sharing Public via Advanced Sharing, and then it behaved the way I intended it to.  It seems like a potentially dangerous behavior.  I wonder if it's some carryover of this "Known Issue" from 2012? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff660257(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little late but it could still help:

Create a junction (\mkdir /J Target Source) and share this one. Now, when you share it, you will get a prompt (at least I did) on your Host PC , asking you actively if you also want to share those other folders in users, which you obviously don't.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just go to users “File -> Properties -> Sharing -> Advanced sharing.” Then uncheck the share button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).